# how to display images in Image control from database in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, webforms

here is the table structure

[image]

this is the code i am using to display images

[image]

This is how its showing please help me with the solutions
[image]

Comment: Please include the code in the question as *text*, not an image. Also, looking at the ASPX page and generated HTML would be more revealing than looking at the result.

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) you should change the type to nvarchar(max) or varchar(max) and then use it like you already do.

Other thing is that you're setting the type png, is it png? it could be jpeg or any other.